# looping over a url

Tags: javascript, d3.js

At the moment I have multiple circles & each of them have their own unique ID. At the moment I have used their unique ID in an object linking to their url page e.g.

```
var link = { 

     1:"http://174.77.29.78:3000/pages/1?"
     2:"http://174.77.29.78:3000/pages/2?"
     3:"http://174.77.29.78:3000/pages/3?"

 };
```

Then in my circle variable I returned the object to link with the circle IDs

```
   .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return link[d.id] ;})
```

As you can imagine, when I eventually put more pages & circles in hardcoding the links isn't practical or efficient at all.

Has anyone examples on how I could make this more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this makes it more efficient, but it should return the same result,

```
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { 
    return "http://174.77.29.78:3000/pages/"+d.id+"?";
})
```

That way you don't need the `link` object and the common part of your url is written only once

Also if your website is located on the same address as your images (http://174.77.29.78:3000) you don't have to include that part in each url. You just need to write the `/pages/1` part. That way if you ever change server you would not have to go through your code and change each and every URL. Your link would become like this,

```
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { 
    return "/pages/"+d.id+"?";
})
```